# Regex c# группы в массив, или IList<string>

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения

Собственно, есть паттерн, который работает, но есть проблема, никак не могу понять как вытащить все начиная от первой группы.

```
var r = new Regex(@"^himikogp?:\/\/*(\/[\w- ./?%&=]*\/\w+\/)*([{0-9}]\w+)$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var m = r.Match(command);
```

Вот строка из которой получаем группы: `himikogp://install/app/987`
Хотелось бы из групп сформировать `IList<string>`, или массив строк. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать метод `Matches` класса `Regex` и организовать цикл по результату, который он вернет:

```
string pattern = "^himikogp?:\/\/*(\/[\w- ./?%&=]*\/\w+\/)*([{0-9}]\w+)$";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(command, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
         Console.WriteLine("{0} at position {1}", match.Value, match.Index);
```

Вместо `Console.WriteLine` делаете, что вам нужно, т.е добавляете в массив `match.Value`.

Comment: Правда код немного жутковат на вид стал, т.к. каст к ToArray не сработал